# killBackgroundProcesses does not work on SETTINGS?

Tags: android

I want to kill the background process of SETTINGS by using killBackgroundProcesses. But it does not work without any errors? I use API(8) level 2.2 and having KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES permission in manifest.

```
  ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE); 
  activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses("com.android.settings");
```

"com.android.settings" is checked by getPackageName of getRunningTasks in ActivityManager.

Answer (score 0):

`killBackgroundProcesses()` silently skips packages that run as the user 'system', which includes *com.android.settings*. In other words, `killBackgroundProcesses()` does not work on system applications.

One easy way to see what user ID a process has is with `adb shell top`, it's ìn the `UID` column:

```
  PID PR CPU% S  #THR     VSS     RSS PCY UID      Name
15828  0   0% S    12 488668K  40124K  fg system   com.android.settings
                                          ^
```

Comment: Are you want how to kill the system processes?

Comment: Sorry, normal applications can't kill system processes for security reasons. Why do you want to kill system processes like Settings?

Comment: We want to create a app installing in android which provide by my company. We need to restrict user opening SETTINGS. Anyone can help me?